# Why does a SQL Query continue if a SELECT statement within a WHERE is incorrect

Tags: sql

Yesterday I needed to make updates to a database changing some user roles and removing some others, so I made a query and one of the lines was this:

```
DELETE FROM [UserRoles]
WHERE RoleId = (SELECT RoleId FROM Roles WHERE Name = 'Rolename')
```

Now I made an error in the SELECT statement. It should have been `SELECT Id` and not `SELECT RoleId`; the Roles table doesn't have a column for `RoleId` it is just `Id`. When I ran the script, instead of failing, it continued to delete *all* UserRoles (luckily I was on a test database). **Why didn't the query fail? What did the Select return to match `RoleId` to everything?**

Comment: Because subqueries are allowed to reference columns from outer queries, and we're quite sure there's a `RoleId` column in `UserRoles` :-|

Comment: Because RoleId exists in your UserRoles table...

Comment: Aside: Dev your scripts in a transaction and rollback / stick a select at the bottom to check your results. For when you aren't as lucky!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so what was the Select returning in the end? `RoleId = RoleId`?

Comment: Yes, it became a correlated subquery where, for each row in the outer query, it was returning that row's `RoleId` column. It's why I'd always advocate using table aliases to prefix column names when writing subqueries - it makes sure you don't accidentally mix inner and outer column references.